Carry and Roll on Interest rate Swap
Only spot starting swaps have a known fixing, F(0,6m). There’s no carry in a
forward starting swap as there’s no certain payments (on the float leg).
This is claimed in an excellent research note  by Lars Peter Lilleøre  in a research note:
https://corporate.nordea.com/api/research/attachment/2796
i am having trouble visualizing:
For forward starting swaps, there’s no carry, and roll simply entails reducing
the forward period. That is, Swp(6M,5Y) becomes Swp(0d,5Y). Similarly,
e.g. Swp(1Y,5Y) becomes Swp(6M,5Y).
This is on page 3.
I will appreciate it if someone can either explain or point me to something basic on this.

What's your question?

A fwd starting swap only has roll down as there is no income earnt if your horizon is less than the fwd start. If I receive 6m5y with a horizon of 3m, in 3m time my 6m5y is 3m5y and under the assumption of an unchanged yield curve my roll pnl will be (6m5y-3m5y) × dv01(3m5y)
